# HTTP Apache - 503 Error - Service Unavailable

Tags: apache-2.2, 503-error

I have installed Drupal 7 on my domain. I wanted to add it my webpage into Google® Webmaster Tools (https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools). I verified ownership (of domain) and I tried to download my page as GoogleBot®, but I received this information : `Unreachable page` and information: `503 Service Unavaliable`. The same happened when I registered on Bing®.

I don't know where is error. I can normally open my page in web browswer without error.  Recently I changed server of my page, I would like to robots index my page.

I give you code of :

- php.ini (I never edited it) :

It's very long, so I added in on [github.com](https://gist.github.com/ty221/8842de2c7cefc724c948).

- .htaccess

It's very long, so I added in on on [github.com](https://gist.github.com/ty221/4712c44696505b6e955e) too.

If you need more files, I will willingly help.

Thanks a lot of any help,

**PS** :
You can download my all logs from here : http://tymonradzik.pl/stackoverflow/Logs.zip

**PPS**:

```
Domain  Type    TTL Answer
tymonradzik.pl. NS  14400   ns4.biznes-host.pl.
tymonradzik.pl. NS  14400   ns3.biznes-host.pl.
tymonradzik.pl. A   14400   91.239.66.80
```

This is my DNS Lookup.

**PPPS**:

[image: My Webmaster tools screenshots]

There is my webmasters tools screenshots.

**PPPPS**:

I don't know whether is that important, but currently my webpage is under maintanece mode in Drupal 7.

Comment: can you check the apache error log and provide any relevant lines please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see clearly that Drupal generated the 503 Service Unavailable error. When you put Drupal in maintenance mode, it serves this error to anyone who is not already logged in with sufficient rights. That includes Googlebot.

To resolve the issue, take Drupal out of maintenance mode.

Comment: Wait please one moment ... i'm checking this...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you doublecheck your DNS and make sure your domain is accessible by others. I often make my own host entries when creating new domains and this might be your dilemma

Comment: I added for you information. Did you read my bounty information : "Please give me the most detailed answer. I can give all files on my server if you only want. " . Please give me more detalis.